# Azure Form Intelligence Connected Container performance

Tags: azure, forms, performance, containers

The Azure documentation provides recommendations for container requirements, suggesting that the recommended container size for a custom template is 8 cores and 24 GB memory. However, it does not specify any performance metrics, such as the number of requests or pages the container can handle on average. Is there any available information regarding this aspect?

Currently, only conducting research. Attempted to find an explanation in Azure documentation but found nothing.

Comment: Azure's performance management for containerized applications is facilitated by monitoring and scaling services such as Azure Monitor for Containers and Azure Container Apps. These tools enable automatic application scaling based on workload demands, utilizing metrics such as CPU and memory usage to ensure that applications stay responsive under varying loads.
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/scaling-options-in-azure-container-apps/ba-p/3878282
&
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/container-insights-custom-metrics?tabs=portal
@Dimitry

Comment: Hi @VinayB,

Apologies for any confusion. My question pertained specifically to certain containers, not general ones.

Nevertheless, I've received information from Microsoft via email regarding Azure Platform Document Intelligence Service performance in average:

- 400 ms for processing a page on the platform service
- 2000 ms for the recommended container.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the email response we received, perhaps this information will be useful for someone else:

> This will vary depending on many factors including the complexity of
> the documents, and the overall number of pages.
> **Without autoscaling enabled** for the Azure platform document intelligence service, here is a comparison of using the minimum
> required compute for a container hosted environment vs the platform
> service using a single page, simple invoice document:
>
> - **~400ms - Platform Service**
> - **~2000ms - Container Service**
>
> Please note that these don't use the exact same model due to the
> capabilities between the two services, but they were trained using the
> same training data and the same field requirements. Assuming you were
> to commit to the same requirements per month with the platform
> service, enabling autoscaling in the platform Document Intelligence
> service would provide you with the same consistency in usage.